# how to show multiple popupmenu in Firemonkey´s TListView based on header/item rightclick

Tags: firemonkey, popupmenu, tlistview

I need to display two different popup menu on a firemonkey´s TListview.

Right click on header shows popup1 and right click on Item shows popup2.

Since Firemonkey´s TListView doesn´t have the "OnContextPopup" event, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should try to use the TListView OnItemClickEx event. That event is called with an ItemIndex argument which will tell you what item was clicked. If it is -1, then the click was on no specific item. This is not really the same as you are asking, as it will also be -1 if the footer is clicked, or if the list is empty, or if it was clicked in the space below the last item. If you need something more specific, then you will have to handle the 3rd argument, MousePos, to understand where the control was clicked... or use another control alltogether as an header. It can get tricky.

Comment: Hi:  Thanks for your tip.

Comment: I use the headers to provide "Master/Detail" layout, so using another control as header won´t work. I´m using ItemClickEx to perform actions when clicking on the detail items. Do you know if It´s possible to use mouse coordinates to get whether clicked listview object is a header accessory?

Comment: If I could get if header´s clicked item was a AcessoryItem, I could call the popup menu from it.

Comment: I also forgot to say, that neither ItemClick nor ItemClickEx event handlers are fired when clicking anywhere but ButtonText on header subobjects.

Comment: I'm not into it this much to help you. Having headers for grouping complicates the use of mouse coordinates a lot. Maybe you should check the TListView source and see how it internally transforms the mouse coordinates to an ItemIndex... that would give you some insight as to how to solve this.